# combo box to change filters on excel pivot table

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

Excel 2013. I am using 3 combo boxes to change filters on the pivot table. 
My first combo box has "Project1", "Project2" & All. 
My second combo box has "Customer1", "Customer2" & All. 
My third combo box has "Country1", "Country2" & All.

I am using 9 pivot tables, all of them have filters as [Project], [Customer], [Country].

My intention is to change first combo box to Project1 & all the pivot tables filter should change as Project1.I am successfully able to do that.

However when I select the first combo box as "All". First Combo box cell link to Y1. I get VBA Run time error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error.

```
Sub ProjectName()

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PVT1").PivotFields("Project Name").ClearAllFilters
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PVT2").PivotFields("Project Name").ClearAllFilters
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PVT3").PivotFields("Project Name").ClearAllFilters

    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PVT1").PivotFields("Project Name").CurrentPage = Range("Y1").Text
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PVT2").PivotFields("Project Name").CurrentPage = Range("Y1").Text
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PVT3").PivotFields("Project Name").CurrentPage = Range("Y1").Text
```

Comment: If you add a breakpoint and go line by line (hitting `F8` to advance), what line gives the error?

Comment: The fourth line gives error when I use breakpoint. ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PVT1").PivotFields("Project Name").CurrentPage = Range("Y1").Text

Comment: Are you using `All` or `(All)`?  The latter is the correct version.

Comment: I did use (All) and it did not help. The code that I am trying to create is in the Report Filter and it is not the Row or Column Filter. So I am using 9 pivot tables, all of them have Report filters as [Project], [Customer], [Country].

Comment: I am really struggling to see where the issue could be.  One workaround could be to surround them all with an `If... Then` to avoid the filter if it is `All`.  Something like `If Range("Y1").Text <> "All" Then : 'filtering code : End If`.  A picture of the combobox might also help.  When you debug, does the expected value come through at `Range("Y1").Text`?

Answer (score 0):

Since the first three lines of code go without issue, I will assume that the Pivot Table `PVT1` and the Field `Project Name` all exist.  This places the error somewhere after that.

For the call to `.CurrentPage` you will get a 1004 error for the following reasons:

- Using this to try and filter any field that is not set as a `Report Filter`.  You cannot use the `CurrentPage` to filter any rows or columns
- Setting a value which does not exist in the list of possible values

On the second point, this is where the call to `Range` might be relevant.

- Verify that the value there exists in the list of possible ones.
- Also be aware you are using `.Text` which will use the *display* value of the cell and not its underlying `.Value`

To resolve these issues, there are a couple of options:

- For the case where you want to filter data that is on the row or column (and not in the filters section) you can go through `PivotItems` and set `Visible = True/False`
- You can also set a label filter from VBA if you want that instead of the manual filter
- If you want to check for a value existing in the `CurrentPage`, you can iterate the `PivotItems` for that `PivotField` and check that one matches.  The code for that is very similar to the `For Each` loop with the check on value, just don't set `Visible`.

**Code** for setting a filter on a row or column

```
Sub FilterPivotField()

    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PVT1")

    Dim pf As PivotField
    Set pf = pt.PivotFields("C")

    pf.ClearAllFilters

    'slow iterates all items and sets Visible (manual filter)
    Dim pi As PivotItem
    For Each pi In pf.PivotItems
        pi.Visible = (pi.Name = Range("J2"))
    Next

    'fast way sets a label filter
    pf.PivotFilters.Add2 Type:=xlCaptionEquals, Value1:=Range("J2")

End Sub
```

**Picture of ranges**

[image]