# excel macro vba Filtering using wildcards

Tags: vba, excel, filtering, wildcard

I need to filter in pivot.
I need to deselect all items starting with "A." and "H."
and keep everything else selected.

the items ranges from:
A.(3-13 characters)
B.(3-13 characters)
all the way to 
Z.(3-13 characters)

the raw data also changes from 50-500 rows (I can have a data with only 50 rows today - then tomorrow I may have over 500)

my current code works: (by entering all possible items which appears on that column - roughly over 300 items) its long but it works.
lately I've been getting more items adding to that list, and I know we can use wild cards.

```
[MY CURRENT CODE]
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("column").ClearAllFilters
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("column"). _
        EnableMultiplePageItems = False
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("column")
    .PivotItems(" PLACE ITEM HERE ").Visible = False
    .PivotItems
    .PivotItems
    .PivotItems [repeat over 300 times - changing the " PLACE ITEM HERE " with the items on the column]
    End With
```

I can cut down the 300+ lines to about 5-10 lines only, I was thinking about something like (below) it would also fix my problem of having new items that are not yet on my list:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("column").ClearAllFilters
        ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("column"). _
        EnableMultiplePageItems = False
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("column")
    .PivotItems("A.*").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("H.*").Visible = False
    End With
```

but this is not working

Comment: Sounds like a `For Each pivotItem in pivotField.PivotItems` is in order here.  Take a look at the `For Each` loop on `PivotItems` in this answer... it should get you started. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30763455/combo-box-to-change-filters-on-excel-pivot-table/30783041#30783041

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
With ActiveCell.PivotTable.PivotFields("Column")
        For i = 1 To .PivotItems.Count
            If .PivotItems(i).Name like "A.*" or .PivotItems(i).Name like "H.*" Then
                .PivotItems(i).Visible = True
            else
                .PivotItems(i).Visible = False
            End If
        Next i
    End With
```

Comment: Thanks, It almost worked. but errors out on 
.PivotItems(i).Visible = True

when ever it goes to the item starting with A. or H.

Comment: Try adding `On Error Resume Next` before the above mentioned code. Maybe it throws an exception when the item is already visible

Comment: Sorry, Didnt see your reply right away, It was running but simply errors out. so I added error handling and it worked exactly how I need it to work.

/thx

Comment: Good answer.  For the error, setting `Visible = True` on a visible item will not error.  This sort of code can throw an error when you get to the last visible `PivotItem`.  The rule for Pivot Tables is that at least one item must be visible, so `Visible = False` on the last item throws an error.  This can be tough to prevent outright but trapping the errors makes it possible to leave a item visible that should be hidden.  (Also, I think you may have flipped which items are supposed to be `Visible` based on the question description.)