# Increase speed of deselect pivotItems from Pivot table using Wildcard*

Tags: excel, vba

the following code deselects PivotItems that start with "xyznames" using a wildcard "*."  It works, however, it is extremely slow.  Any ideas as to do the same thing, but faster?

```
Sub UncheckxyzName()
'Purpose: Uncheck "xyzname* from Pivot tables from "Comparison" tab

 Dim pt As PivotTable
 Dim myPI As PivotItem

'stop Excel actions for speed enhancement
With Excel.Application
   .ScreenUpdating = False
   .EnableEvents = False
   .Calculation = Excel.xlCalculationManual
   .DisplayStatusBar = False
End With

'uncheck "xyzname*" from "Comparison" tab
With Worksheets("Comparison").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Type")
    .PivotItems("fnBid").Visible = False
End With

 With Worksheets("Comparison").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Resource Name")

 For Each myPI In .PivotItems
 myPI.Visible = True
 Next myPI

 For Each myPI In .PivotItems
    If myPI.name Like "xyzname*" Then
        myPI.Visible = False
    Else
        myPI.Visible = True
    End If
    Next myPI
 End With

'Turn back on Excel actions 
With Excel.Application
    .DisplayStatusBar = True
    .Calculation = Excel.xlCalculationAutomatic
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

End Sub
```

Related to post:

[excel macro vba Filtering using wildcards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30808958/excel-macro-vba-filtering-using-wildcards)

Answer (score 1):

this loop:

```
For Each myPI In .PivotItems
myPI.Visible = True
Next myPI
```

is unnecessary, you iterate through every items twice, once making them all visible and then visible or not based on `Like` condition. Assuming the reason your macro is slow is iterating through huge amount of `PivotItems` deleting this loop wil make it twice faster.

Comment: Good catch, avb.  I removed that chunk of code and re-ran.  It's bit faster, but not by twice as fast.  Although, your advice certainly helped cut down the time taken.  The entire code is looping through three pivots on three different worksheets.  Each pivot contains approx. 368 pivot items.

Comment: Just wondering if there is another way to uncheck these wildcard items without looping?